# sql tempdb modify file created 2nd file

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following script:

```
    use master
    go
    alter database tempdb modify file
    (Name = tempdev, filename= 'g:\databases\tempdb.mdf');
    go
```

created a 2nd copy of tempdb (after restarting the server) in the new location.  Only one file(new) shows in the tempdb properties in Management Studio, and the new file is being used.
Can I safely just delete the old tempdb file?

Comment: Yes.  But you might feel better if you just rename it first and then bring up the database.

Comment: Gordon is right, it seems to add a second mdf file replacing the original one but the first one is not used any more.